# php class attribute inizialized in the cunstroctor not retaining value

Tags: php, class, methods

I'm trying working on adding class into the project and after initializing the class attribute in the constructor it seems that the class is not retaining the value.

if I force the attribute value in the method, I get what I want. Am I missing something?

```
class test {
    public $test_var;

    public function __constructor(){
        $this->test_var = 'hello';
    }

    public function add_record(){
//        $this->test_var = 'hello';

        print $this->test_var;
    }
}

$test = new test();
$test->add_record();
```

Answer (score 1):

__contructor is not what you want. It should be

```
 public function __construct(){
```

Comment: you called it __contructor but the correct syntax is __construct (without 'or' in the end)